# jquery ui datepicker doesn't work after body replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

​i'm working on a project where the page-content is updated via ajax. the whole body is replaced.

now i wanted (or have to) use the jquery datepicker. it works until the content of the page is updated. i can see in the dom, that the datepicker uses a appended div which is removed by my body update. so after the update the datepicker doesn't work anymore. i think the plugin tries to work with the removed calendar div, which is not available anymore after the update.

here's my example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').html('<input type="text" />');
    $('input').datepicker();
    $('body').html('<input type="text" />');
    $('input').datepicker();
});​
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUwu9/

any ideas how i can get the datepicker back to work after replacing the page-body?

Comment: any reason why you replace the whole 'body'? why not just put you content inside a div

Comment: I found the solution after searching more and more...

after updating the body it is needed to append the datepicker div like this:

    $('body').append($.datepicker.dpDiv);

found it here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5679

Comment: I think my solution is more simple. add a new div should break anything. pls see my answer

Comment: the solution is before applying datepicker after the body replacement simple set this: $.datepicker.initialized = false;

Answer (score 0):

if you put your content inside a `div`, instead of the `body`, it will work

http://jsfiddle.net/ZUwu9/1/

so just put a div inside body, and apply all actions to this dev

Comment: i know. but we're using a framework that has this behaviour. i can't change this. but i found the solution here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5679

Comment: OK, but I think a good framework should give you the option about which html element you want to be replaced when ajax calls completes. Anyway, you have solved it. :)

Comment: its not a good framework and i have not choosen it :-) but thanks for your efforts

Answer (score -1):

Attach it to a delegated event handler.

```
$('body').on('focus', 'input', function(){
   $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: @Sure612 that example you linked me works just as expected. I'm not sure why you downvoted me.

Comment: i can not vote down. i don't have enough reputation. maybe it works as (you have) expected, but it does not solve the problem.